# SQL/Criteria Query CONTAINS ALL?

Tags: java, sql, criteria, contains, criteria-api

```
Table A:        Table A_B:         Table B:
id | a          a_id | b_id        id | b
------          -----------        ------
1  | w          1    | 1           1  | s
2  | x          1    | 2           2  | t
3  | y          2    | 4           3  | u
4  | z          4    | 4           4  | v
```

Now I'd like to have ALL entries from table A WHERE B.id = 1 AND B.id = 2.

At the moment I have to following code:

```
SELECT *
FROM A a
JOIN A_B ab ON a.id    = ab.a_id
JOIN B b    ON ab.b_id = b.id
```

And here I got stuck. `WHERE b.id IN (...)` gives me all entries from Table A WHERE `b.id = 1 OR b.id = 2`of course, and `WHERE b.id = 1 AND b.id = 2` gives no results at all...

The only possible solution I found is using `INTERSECT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM A a
JOIN A_B ab ON a.id    = ab.a_id
JOIN B b    ON ab.b_id = b.id
WHERE b.id = 1

INTERSECT

SELECT *
FROM A a
JOIN A_B ab ON a.id    = ab.a_id
JOIN B b    ON ab.b_id = b.id
WHERE b.id = 2
```

But I can have an infinite number of b.ids. So this query will become really slow...

Isn't there something like `IN` which behaves like I want? And it should be implemented using Criteria Query:

```
Join<A, B> aB = root.join(A_.bs); // as this is a @ManyToMany relationship
...
```

But I'd also be happy with a pure SQL solution.

Comment: i'm not sure I understand the question correctly but I think this is a case for left join http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html

Comment: Your example would be clearer if you change the record in A_B from 2,4 to 2,2. Then indicate that record 2 in table A should not be returned despite matching the one value (because it doesn't match the other value).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested on MySQL:

```
select TableA.id, count(*)
from tableA
join tableA_B on TableA.id=TableA_B.a_id
where b_id =1 or b_id=2
group by tableA.id
having count(*)=2
```

[SQL Fiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8e129/4).

Comment: This relies on counting... so it would return too many records if, for example, A_B contains the record 2,2 twice.

Answer (score 0):

I must admit I don't really follow the question and the problem, but are you saying that this doesn't work:

```
SELECT *
FROM B b
LEFT JOIN A_B ab ON b.id    = ab.b_id
LEFT JOIN A a    ON ab.a_id = a.id
WHERE b.id IN (1,2)
```

Comment: Read it again. I found a solution using INTERSECT. But your query just gives me results from Table A where b.id = 1 OR b.id = 2. But I want all entries from Table A where b.id = 1 AND b.id = 2.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, this is a many-to-many relation, and you want to filter the data based on the Id on table `B`.

First, your first query seems ok to me; I would write it as follows for clarity:

```
select 
    a.id, a.a, b.id, b.b
from 
    A as a
    inner join A_B as ab on a.id = ab.a_id
    inner join B as b on ab.b_id = b.id;
```

Now, if you want all the records for which `b.id = 1` **or** `b.id = 2`, this should work:

```
select 
    a.id, a.a, b.id, b.b
from 
    A as a
    inner join A_B as ab on a.id = ab.a_id
    inner join B as b on ab.b_id = b.id
where
    b.id in (1,2);
```

Check this [SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/9e9348/2)

Hope this helps

Comment: Hey, thanks. I should have written a SQL fiddle... I modified yours: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6628f/1 (Changed the entries in A_B table). The result should now only contains a.id = 1, because it's the only entry which matches b.id = 1 AND b.id = 2